# combining data from two tables with same primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
table1
id   | name  | location
------------------------
1    | brian | null
2    | john  | null
```

and another table like this:

```
table2
id   | location
------------------------
2    |  USA
1    |  China
```

I want to INSERT the locations into the table1 ON t1.id=t2.id so table1 looks like this:

```
table1
id   | name  | location
------------------------
1    | brian | China
2    | john  | USA
```

For some reason though, when I run

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT location FROM table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id;
```

I get a syntax error. Does anyone know how to insert it correctly?

Comment: Don't under any circumstances share that error message with us.

Comment: Insert would create a new record. What you are looking for is update. But I'm curious why you would want to denormalise your data by moving location into the first table

Comment: Your `location` field in `table1` has no purpose in 3rd Normal Form. Get rid of it, then: `SELECT t1.name, t2.location FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you want to update Table1:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.location = t2.location;
```

Comment: this still returns a syntax error

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select t1.location = t2.location' at line 4.

Comment: Yes I saw it. A typo, I wrote SELECT instead of SET. See my edited answer.

Comment: See a demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hRrJxMtehJuVmePPYPfQ96/0

Comment: ah it works, thank you very much!